# create form using play-framework 2.5.x java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to create a simple html form using **playframework 2.5.3**

I am following [official documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaForms)

I am stuck at a point

`Form<User> userForm = formFactory.form(User.class);`

Intellij(16) says, **cannot resolve symbol formFactory**

I  have allready imported `import play.data.FormFactory;`

Thankyou..!

Comment: Besides importing the package you need to inject the factory: `@Inject FormFactory formFactory;` Did you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you:
[image]

the doc of play framework has already tell you how to use play.data.form

Answer (score 0):

But IDEA tells you it can't find formFactory variable declared.
Try to rebuild project from the console. And then re-open it in IDEA.